# autotools: how to deal with a source generated by configure?

Tags: build, dependencies, autotools, autoconf, automake

Let's imagine a minimal project with the following structure:

```
|-- configure.ac
|-- Makefile.am
|-- src/
    `-- ...
|-- test/
    `-- Makefile.am
    `-- test.sh
    `-- test.py.in
```

Now, `test.py.in` uses autotools variables to build `test.py`. Running `configure` does build `test.py` and I'm quite happy about it.

But, touching/**modifying `test.py.in` and then running `make check` should run `configure` before actually testing, but it does not. How to?**

---

My `Makefile.am`:

```
check_SCRIPTS = \
    test.sh \
    $(NULL)

check_PROGRAMS = \
    $(NULL)

testsuite_bin_SOURCES = \
    $(NULL)

TESTS = \
    test.sh \
    $(NULL)

MOSTLYCLEANFILES = \
    *.out *.err *.log \
    $(NULL)

EXTRA_DIST = \
    test.sh \
    test.py \
    $(NULL)
```

Running `make check` when `test.py` has been `rm`ed:

```
$ make check
make   test.sh 
make[1]: Entering directory `.../test'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `test.sh'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `.../test'
make  check-TESTS
make[1]: Entering directory `.../test'
*** './test.py' was not found - aborting test ***
FAIL: test.sh
=======================================
1 of 1 test failed
Please report to nobody@nohost.nodomain
=======================================
make[1]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/test
make: *** [check-am] Error 2
```

---

Part of my `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
    #...
    test/Makefile
    test/test.py
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: How exactly does your `configure.ac` create the file?  This affects the answer; `AC_CONFIG_FILES` should be handled automatically by Automake, but if you create the file by hand then you have to write your own rules.

Comment: @TomTromey Yes, I use `AC_CONFIG_FILES` to build the file. I've edited my question to show you how.

Comment: When you touch `tests.py.in` does `config.status` get re-run?  I would expect that but not a re-run of `configure`.

Comment: (And BTW, sorry, I misunderstood the question at first.)

Comment: @TomTromey Whenever I `touch` `test.py.in` and `make check`, `config.status` is left unmodified as a `stat` on the file show me.

Comment: Yeah -- `config.status` is an output of `configure`.  However, it should be re-executed in order to regenerate `test.py` from `test.py.in`.  Re-running `configure` is only really done if one of the inputs to `configure` changes, such as touching `configure.ac`.

Comment: @TomTromey How to make `config.status` run automatically when I `touch test.py.in`?

Comment: Automake should take care of that automatically.